# Getting the text of an <a> with XPath when it's buried in another tag e.g. <strong>

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xhtml

The following XPath is usually sufficient for matching all anchors whose text contains a certain string:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'SENIOR ASSOCIATES')]
```

Given a case like this though:

```
<a href="http://www.freshminds.net/job/senior-associate/"><strong>
                        SENIOR ASSOCIATES <br> 
                        </strong></a>
```

The text is wrapped in a `<strong>`, also there's also a `<br>` before the anchor closes, and so the above XPath returns nothing.

How can the XPath be adapted so that it allows for the `<a>` containing additional tags such as `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<b>`, `<br>` etc. while still working in the standard case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `text()`.

```
//a[contains(., 'SENIOR ASSOCIATES')]
```

---

Contrary to what you might think, `text()` does not give you the text of an element.

It is a node test, i.e. an expression that selects a list of actual nodes (!), namely *the text node children* of an element.

Here:

```
<a href="http://www.freshminds.net/job/senior-associate/"><strong>
                    SENIOR ASSOCIATES <br> 
                    </strong></a>
```

there are no text node children of `a`. All the text nodes are children of `strong`. So `text()` gives you zero nodes.

Here:

```
<a href="http://www.freshminds.net/job/senior-associate/"> <strong>
                    SENIOR ASSOCIATES <br> 
                    </strong></a>
```

there is one text node child of `a`. It's empty (as in "whitespace only").

---

`.` on the other hand selects only one node (the context node, the `<a>` itself).

Now, `contains()` expects strings as its arguments. If one argument is not a string, a conversion to string is done first.

Converting a node set (consisting of 1 or more nodes) to string is done by concatenating all text node descendants of the first node in the set<sup>(*)</sup>. Therefore using `.` (or its more explicit equivalent `string(.)`) gives you `SENIOR ASSOCIATES` surrounded by a bunch of whitespace, because there is a bunch of whitespace in your XML.

To get rid of that whitespace, use the `normalize-space()` function:

```
//a[contains(normalize-space(.), 'SENIOR ASSOCIATES')]
```

or, shorter, because "the current node" is the default for this function:

```
//a[contains(normalize-space(), 'SENIOR ASSOCIATES')]
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> That's the reason why using `//a[contains(.//text(), 'SENIOR ASSOCIATES')]` would work in the first of the two samples above but not in the second one.

Comment: Superb answer. Still getting those tabs and newlines though using your final form. See here: http://pastebin.com/Tbp4Qa8p

Comment: @Pyderman `normalize-space()` does not remove whitespace from the result node, it only removes whitespace from the argument to `contains()`.

Comment: Yes, it's there to allow *matching* independently of source code format. It does not change what XPath returns, it changes what XPath operates on.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I see.

Comment: @Tomalak Have you any idea why the approach doesn't work on this site. i.e. `//a[contains(normalize-space(), 'Sales Specialist')]` returns no matches https://www.softcat.com/join-us/career-opportunities?p=jobs%2Fsales%3Fc%3DSales

Comment: @Pyderman My crystal ball tells me: Because the stuff you seem to be interested in lies in an `<iframe>` and you execute the XPath against the top level document.

Comment: @Tomalak Thy crystal ball doth speaketh the truth.